# Asus FX504 BIOS boot issue

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, installation, bios

I recently bought an Asus FX504 laptop which I wanted to upgrade the HDD + Intel Optane with my SSD.

After removing both the hardware above and installing my SSD, I am entering the BIOS each time I turn on the laptop.

The SSD has an OS already from a previous laptop, and I also have a bootable USB pen with Windows 10 files so I can reinstall a fresh copy of Windows.

I have read people having the same struggle but I don't seem to find a solution.

Things I have tried/to be considered:

- Disabled Secure Boot and Fast Boot however I am still unable to either boot from my HD or USB pen. (Unable to locate an option for CSM in "Boot" menu which I read should be enabled.)
- The Boot menu is empty so I am seemingly unable to change the boot order.
- Removed CMOS battery for a minute.
- USB pen is fine as its being detected and bootable by another laptop.
- Both SSD and USB is being detected in the BIOS main screen.

This is driving me mad! Any help is much appreciated.
(Pictures to follow I hope

Goal: Boot from USB drive to re-install Windows.

Setup:
Laptop: Asus FX504GD-E4673T
BIOS: American Megatrends 312
EXISTING Hard Drive: HHD + Intel Optane
NEW Hard Drive: Samsung 850 EVO

BIOS images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bv3UX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Press and hold ESC key while the unit starts to access boot menu.

from [Tom's Hardware Guide](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-1973164/change-asus-boot-order.html)

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your suggestion. This is empty when pressing Esc and I can only enter the main BIOS page (https://imgur.com/NYXi6vQ)

Comment: @user981105 on the bios screen your USBs are "Port N/A"  try to enable these on the main or advanced page and make sure they are plugged into mobo correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry but during the BIOS picture the USB was not plugged in. https://imgur.com/Btj1cBU shows the USB is being detected. Thanks.

Comment: @user981105  <F7> for advanced mode and look for CSM?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple new BIOS iterations after ver. 312. [The newest is ver. 317](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX504/HelpDesk_BIOS/). I would suggest updating the newest BIOS and confirming USB boot capabilities again.

The Boot Menu picture you have given seems to indicate as if it's completely blank, which isn't normal. I'd suggest updating the BIOS to see if this continues. Also, confirm that your USB flash drive functions on another computer as a bootable media.